# PROMPT_COMMAND output in shell script using piping LINUX

Tags: linux, shell-script, pipe, prompt

I want to make a shell script that shows the available data on my root directory and shows it continuously after each new command in the prompt by using PROMPT_COMMAND in the shell script. However, I can get the available data, but I don't know how to apply the PROMPT_COMMAND to read the available data so that it works. I have to specifically use PROMPT_COMMAND to do this.

Now I have this in my script:

```
df -h /root |awk '{print $4}'| grep "." | PROMPT_COMMAND= ""
```

Any ideas on how to use the PROMT_COMMAND in my script so that it works and gives me the correct output?

I am indeed using bash. The grep function was indeed redundant.

Comment: Hello and welcome to unix.se  I am a bit puzzled about the request: you want to show that space usage : in part of your prompt (in an interactive shell) ? or in a shell script ? Could you please show us 2 or more exemples of the output you want to have, and where you want it? And if it is interactive, you can also show the result of :  `ps -ef | grep " $$ " | egrep -v " grep | ps "` so we know what shell you are using (bash? ksh? zsh? another?). Even for a script solution: please precise which shell you will use in it (ie, which shebang you'll use : `#!/usr/bin/bash` ? or another?)

Comment: and do you really intend to show only the /root directory? or rather need to look at the ~  (the home directory of the person loggued it, ie  /root for root, /home/foo for user foo ?) : then do the df on `~` instead

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `grep "."`? If that's grepping lines that contain at least a `.`, that should be `grep -F .` or `grep '\.'`, but the available space field doesn't necessarily have a `.`. On my system ATM, it's 14G

Answer (score 2):

`$PROMPT_COMMAND` is specific to the `bash` shell. It's a special variable that is meant to contain bash code that is evaluated before each prompt is displayed, so it's only relevant in interactive shells (not scripts) and it should rather be something like:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='
  available_space_on_root_fs=$(df -h --output=avail /)
  available_space_on_root_fs=${available_space_on_root_fs##*[[:space:]]}
'
PS1='$available_space_on_root_fs$ '
```

You'd typically put that in your `~/.bashrc` (and have some code in your `~/.bash_profile` that sources `~/.bashrc` when the shell is interactive).

In `zsh`, the equivalent is the `precmd` function. While you can also have parameter expansions in the prompt after you set the `promptsubst` option there, setting `psvar` *n*<sup>th</sup> element and refer to them as `%nv` is generally safer:

```
precmd() psvar[1]=${$(df -h --output=avail /)[-1]}
PS1='%1v$ '
```

(in `~/.zshrc`)

Instead of setting the global `precmd` hook, you can also add a function name to the `precmd_functions` array:

```
determine-avail-space() psvar[1]=${$(df -h --output=avail /)[-1]}
precmd_functions+=(determine-avail-space)
PS1='%1v$ '
```

The above assumes GNU `df` for the `--output=avail` and `-h` options (the latter now found in quite a few other implementations). On Linux, see also `findmnt -no avail /` which gives the result without header.

Note that what we call the root FS is the one mounted on `/`. `/root` is usually the home directory of the `root` user. `/root` is invariably on the root fs as it's important the root account be available and fully operational even when other FS are not mounted so `df /` and `df /root` should give you the same information.

Answer (score 0):

That is command:

```
df -h /root |awk '{print $4}'| grep "."
```

PROMPT_COMMAND is a variable which hold a command. So:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="df -h /root |awk '{print $4}'| grep \".\""
```

Done.

Comment: The `$4` is within double quotes, so will be expanded to the shell's 4th positional parameter (likely unset) so `PROMPT_COMMAND` will actaually contain `df -h /root |awk '{print }'| grep "."`

Comment: the grep . doesn't do much (it would only get rid of empty lines, ie lines with no characters on it except the final newline,  and the df -h /root will not generate any). And like @StéphaneChazelas said: the englobing " will make the shell interpret the $4, and the command will thus not be what's intended. use ' instead (and then only replace the `awk '...'` by `awk '\'' .... '\''` ). ie : `PROMPT_COMMAND=' df -h /root |awk '\'' {print $4} '\'' '`  # the latter part could be just : '\'  but would be less easy to remember to edit it as the one I propose if one wants to add something after it

Comment: The dollar sign can be escaped as well (`\$`), eliminating the need for `'\''`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the size of the homedir displayed in front of your usual prompt, and are using bash:

```
#you can place the later inside your .bashrc once you are satisfied it works:
PROMPT_COMMAND=' df -h ~ | tail -n 1 | awk '\''{print $(NF-2),$(NF-1), $NF }'\'' | xargs printf "%s " '

# this will display:  available, %of_usage, and name  before your usual prompt:
354Mb 68% /root [usual prompt here] # 

# it is better to have it displayed not before the prompt line, but on a separate line, so:
PROMPT_COMMAND=' df -h ~ | tail -n 1 | awk '\''{print $(NF-2),$(NF-1), $NF }'\'' '

# will display it before the prompt line, not messing up with bash computation of the prompt-line length
354Mb 68% /root 
[usual prompt here] #
```

Comment: That will mess up cursor positioning. `$PROMPT_COMMAND` should not print things on the same line as the prompt.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas : good point, especially when going up in the history. Then juch change the printf "%s" to printf "%s\n" (or even just get rid of the | xargs altogether) to have it on the line before

Comment: There should be no need for `tail`, `xargs` or `printf` here. `awk`  can do their jobs.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: I try to make it as easy to grasp as possible, but indeed awk '(NR>1) { printf("%s %s %s\n", $(NF-2), $(NF-1), $NF) }' could also work. TIMTOWTDI, but some are less easy to grasp to newcomers, imo